# Lazy caterer's sequence, cutting pizza into most pieces with n straight cuts. Graph theory proof.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

is there a way to solve this problem using graph theory? I used Euler's formula to find that when you use the method in which every new line intersects the old line in different places gives you $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+1.$

proof.

Make make the intersections of line segments the vertices and the parts of these line segments joining the vertices the edges.

The number of times any line intersects is $n-1$ (without counting the two times it intersects the circle). Therefore the number of vertices is V=$\frac{(n-1)*n}{2}+2n=\frac{(n+3)(n)}{2}$
since each inner vertex is counted twice and each line intersects the circle twice.

each line segment is partitioned into n line segments and the circle is partitioned into $2n$ edges.

$E=n(n+2)$

using Euler's formula we know $\frac{(n+3)(n)}{2}+F-n(n-2)=2$

therefore $F=n(n-2)- \frac{(n+3)(n)}{2}+2$ so $F=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+2$

however we counted the outside face also so without that face:

> the pizza is cut into $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$ faces as desired.

Is there a way to use this to prove this is the greatest value of F for a fixed n?

Comment: I found this, I can't read it though http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2686448?uid=3738664&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102013130047